# What is the difference between "Der Entzug" and "Das Entziehen"?

Tags: meaning, nominalization

Why is it "Das Entziehen des Führerscheins" and not "Der Entzug des Führerscheins"? Do those two words have different meanings?

Note: German is my first language but I still don't know.

Edit: This question came up while looking up "Das Entziehen des Führerscheins". I feel like "Der Entzug" is more commonly used but the official "Bußgeldkatalog" uses "Das Entziehen"

Comment: Why do you think one is more correct than the other? Indeed, the compound word normally is "Führerscheinentzug". To me, the first puts more stress on the actual process while the latter could also be the state of not having a license.

Comment: Because "Der Entzug" is imo more commonly used but the official "Bußgeldkatalog" uses "Das Entziehen". So I was wondering if there actually is a difference between the two and why one would use one over the other

Comment: For future reference, if German is your first language then you can ask the question in German and expect to have it answered in German. Generally only people who are learning German ask questions in English.

Comment: Wenn deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist, wie du sagst, dann darfst du hier gerne auch auf Deutsch schreiben.

Comment: @RDBury,tofro Mein Fehler, danke!

Answer (score 2):

As nominalization *Entziehung* only works for the active part, the party who triggers or performes the withdrawal, so its applicable on side of the court ordering or the police executing it.

> Die Entziehung der Fahrerlaubnis durch ein Gericht wird in § 69 Strafgesetzbuch geregelt.

*Entzug* works equally well for the passive part who gets something withdrawn. Assumed we are talking about alcohol,

> Ich bin gerade auf Entzug

surely specifies, that you are the one not getting alcoholic drinks, but it makes no statement about the active party. Same on this example:

> ..., dass das Morphium und auch sein Entzug verheerende Wirkungen hätten.

The impact is on the person no longer getting morphine, the passive side. For the other side its their job.

Answer (score 2):

Eigentlich ist die *Entziehung* die Tätigkeit oder der Vorgang, die zum *Entzug* (vollendete Tatsache) führt.

Comment: Nicht die *Entziehung*, sondern *das Entziehen*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Duden listet *Entziehung* und *Entziehen* als Synonyme.

Comment: Das ergibt überhaupt keinen Sinn ohne jegliche Begründung. Unterdurchschnittliche Antwort, nach unten mit dir

Answer (score -1):

The Strafgesetzbuch uses both. For reference, Freiheitsentzieh- appears 30 times, Freiheotsentzug only once, and the text is composed over the course of decades. This should be parallel to Führerscheinentzug.

> Das Gericht bestimmt, dass eine Anrechnung nach Absatz 4 auch auf eine verfahrensfremde Strafe erfolgt, wenn deren Vollzug für die verurteilte Person eine unbillige Härte wäre. Bei dieser Entscheidung sind insbesondere das Verhältnis der Dauer des bisherigen **Freiheitsentzugs** zur Dauer der verhängten Strafen, der erzielte Therapieerfolg und seine konkrete Gefährdung sowie das Verhalten der verurteilten Person im Vollstreckungsverfahren zu berücksichtigen.

> Hat der Verurteilte aus Anlaß einer Tat, die Gegenstand des Verfahrens ist oder gewesen ist, Untersuchungshaft oder eine andere **Freiheitsentziehung** erlitten, so wird sie auf zeitige Freiheitsstrafe und auf Geldstrafe angerechnet.

It appears that you are not alone in that the law makers change it up sporadically.